# How can set the title of all the links in a page

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make some javascript code that once run adds a title of each link that is the title of the page it leads to. Sorry, all I can figure out is...

```
<body onload="replace()">

<script>
  function replace() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a").title=this.href;
  }
</script>

<a href="hi">hi</a>
<a href="hi2">hi2</a>
<a href="hi3">hi3</a>

</body>
```

But nothing happens and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

more simple, just place correctly your script:

```
<body>

<a href="hi">hi</a>
<a href="hi2">hi2</a>
<a href="hi3">hi3</a>


<!-- Script for everything, just placed before  </body>-->
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(A=>{ A.title = A.href })
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements, you need to use loop for setting whatever to each link.

```
<body onload="replace()">
<script>
function replace() {
    // find all links 
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    // loop the collection and set title to each one
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].title = links[i].href;
    }
}
</script>
<a href="hi">hi</a>
<a href="hi2">hi2</a>
<a href="hi3">hi3</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, there is no way to detect a page title from a different page in JS.  If you know the titles in advance, you can create a mapping object and loop over your links like so:

```
var map = [['link','title'],['link','title']];

$('a').each(function() {
  for(var i=0; i<map.length; i++) {
    if(map[i][0] == $(this).attr('src'))
      $(this).attr('title', map[i][1]);
  }
});
```

That should set all your links with the appropriate page titles based on matching the src attributes of each link against the link in your mapping object

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location.href instead of this.href. Also, you probably need to run through each link in the tag list:

```js
function start() {
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].title = window.location.href;
  }
}

window.load = start();
```

```html
<a href="hi">hi</a>
<a href="hi2">hi2</a>
<a href="hi3">hi3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer, I have tried to add comments so that you could understand what has happened:

```
<a class="link" href="about.html">About</a>
<a class="link" href="careers.html">Careers</a>
<a class="link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>

<script>
    //create a true array
    var links = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));

    window.addEventListener(
        "load", //Trigger Load event of window object
        ()=> //return this function
        { 
            //links is an array of a-tag objects
            for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
            {
                //for each a tag object 
                //set the attribute targeted below
                links[i].setAttribute
                (
                    //target the title attribute
                    "title",
                    //set it to the current href attribute value of the that a-tag object
                    links[i].getAttribute("href")
                );
            }
        }
    );

</script>
```